# Does Eclipse have a line-by-line comparison and merge option/plugin?

Tags: java, eclipse, compare, diff

Sometimes, I have 2 very similar files (in that the algorithm the code implements is exactly the same, but some of the variables are different) that I want to make the same changes to (e.g. adding comments).

as an example, File1.java:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
map.put(Constants.TYPE_1, variable);
```

And File2.java;

```
Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
map.put(Constants.TYPE_2, variable);
```

And yes, I know that similar code should probably be abstracted out into an inherited class. Just assume that's not possible here because the code is just different enough due to how it interacts with the front-end that it's not really possible to make a readable abstraction.

If I want to add the same comment to both files for clarification, I can add this in one file and then copy it over to the next. However, I might have a dozen or so comments I'd like to duplicate, and I might want to do this over multiple files.

Now, I thought I could do this using the Eclipse "compare to... each other" functionality, but the problem is that if I add a comment right before the map.put() call and then compare the 2 files, it considers this change together with the other Constants.variable difference as 1 difference and attempting to merge the comment will bring with it the TYPE_2 difference, which is what I don't want.

I want to be able to compare line by line and merge differences line by line, is that possible in Eclipse 2020-06?

Comment: You can edit it directly. For example, if a change covers 3 lines, you can copy and paste only 2 line of it using Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V in the merge/compare editor.

Comment: @howlger that helps somewhat, but it's still having to copy paste over manually.

Comment: IMHO in such cases a dialog should pop up telling "Don't repeat yourself!" that cannot be closed for at least 5 seconds. ;)